# Run FFMPEG multiple overlay commands in one command

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, drawtext, fluent-ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to do more operation on one  video
the operation that i want to do is add many text in difference time, audio and image.
i can do all of them but not in one command, Do all separately

any suggestions to do multiple text , overlay image and audio in one command

Thanks

Comment: That's what a filter_complex allows. Multiple filters chained in serial and parallel ways. What specifically do you want done?

Comment: I want to insert photo to video using this command

Ffmpeg –I  input.mp4 –I img.png  -filter_complex “[0:v][1:v]” overlay=15 :15:enable=between(t,10,20)”  output.mp4

then 
i want to draw text using this command 

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "drawtext=enable='between(t,12,3*60)':fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSerif.ttf: text='Test Text'" -acodec copy output.mp4

i will draw text more than one time in different  time of video
Then 
merge audio to the video using this 
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp4 -map 0.0 -map 1.0 -acodec copy -qscale 4 -vcodec mpeg4 outvideo.mp4

Comment: So can i merge this 3 commands in one command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the commands provided in comments in one execution, use

```
ffmpeg –i input.mp4 –i img.png -i audio.mp4 -filter_complex \
       "[0:v][1:v]overlay=15 :15:enable=between(t,10,20), \
        drawtext=enable='between(t,12,3*60)': \
        fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefon‌​t/FreeSerif.ttf: text='Test Text'[v]" \
       -map "[v]" -map 2:a -acodec copy -qscale 4 -vcodec mpeg4 outvideo.mp4
```

To add more drawtext filters, insert them after the first drawtext filter e.g.

```
ffmpeg –i input.mp4 –i img.png -i audio.mp4 -filter_complex \
       "[0:v][1:v]overlay=15 :15:enable=between(t,10,20), \
        drawtext=enable='between(t,12,3*60)': \
        fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefon‌​t/FreeSerif.ttf: text='Test Text', \
        drawtext=enable='between(t,12,3*60)': \
        fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefon‌​t/FreeSerif.ttf: text='Text2'[v]" \
       -map "[v]" -map 2:a -acodec copy -qscale 4 -vcodec mpeg4 outvideo.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks .. is that works in ffmpeg n2.4.2 
i'm using this exampe to run ffmpeg in android but the comma seems to not separate the filters!
https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java
any suggestion ?
Thanks